# Contextual Action Bar in Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-3.0-honeycomb, contextual-action-bar

I'm looking to copy the action bar implementation from the gmail app in Honeycomb

Unfortunately I can't post an image because I'm new here.

Basically, when you select an email or more your action bar animates into a different action bar with:
1.Contextual buttons

2.A new "Done" button appears over the Home icon.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Call the [`startActionMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#startActionMode%28android.view.ActionMode.Callback%29) method available on any View or your Activity. This method accepts an [`ActionMode.Callback`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.Callback.html) object that will manage the lifecycle of the contextual mode. `startActionMode` will return an [`ActionMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.html) object if starting the mode was successful, or `null` if the request was rejected.

If you are specifically creating a multiple selection mode for a ListView, you can take a shortcut and use `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL`.